# Cannot query DynamoDB using QueryAsync and partition key

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My data model looks like this:

```
[DynamoDBTable("prices")]
public class Price
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey("id")]
    public String Id { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty("symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty("expdate")]
    public long ExpDate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to query DynamoDB using `QueryAsync` like this:

```
var q = db.QueryAsync<Price>("ID");
```

I'm always getting a `InvalidOperationException` despite only using the partition key to query my table.

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Must have one range key or a GSI index defined for the table prices'`

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: the table name nor the key name match from the error, query to your table schema, can you fix those and make sure you are posting the right error?

Comment: That error says to me that the table has a sort key and you are not including it.

Comment: @Kirk No, the table doesn't have a sort key, I checked it in the AWS console

Comment: @WarrenParad I fixed the wrong names, the error is the same. I noticed the AWS docs say that you can't query a table without a sort key using the  .NET Object Persistence Model. What's the reason behind that? I can query tables using `AmazonDynamoDBClient` but not `DynamoDBContext` when a sort key isn't defined?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.QueryScan.html

Comment: because it sucks? Use the abstracted object model and not the Persistence Model, it doesn't moke any sense

Comment: Probably true, but it's easy to use and you don't have to work with endless nested objects for a simple query. It's similar to EF Core and has the most convenience.

Answer (score 3):

If your table has just a Hash key then you should use the "LoadAsync" method instead of QueryAsync.
It will return null if the key does not exist.

```cs
var item = await _db.LoadAsync<Price>("ID");
```

> If your table has a simple primary key (partition key), you can't use the Query method. Instead, you can use the Load method and provide the partition key to retrieve the item.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetDynamoDBContext.html#w20aac17c17c21c35c31

Comment: I found that too but it's weird, I can query a table with just a hash key using the Java provider with no problems. It's a design flaw in the .NET provider. I created a GitHub issue for this.